# REDIS as pefect LRU

Tags: redis, lru

I want to use REDIS following perfect LRU eviction policy. For experimentation purpose I set the maxmemory size of the Redis.This maxmemory REDIS can have maximum 10 key/value pair of fix data size. I set "maxmemory-policy :allkeys-lru" and maxmemory-samples :10 . When I insert new key/value pair it does not remove the oldest visited key/value pair.why is it not removing the oldest key when the sample size is same as the maximum number of keys it can have.

So what should be the behaviour of allkeys-lru eviction policy when maxmemory-samples=maximum number of possible key/value pair in redis ?

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your documentation.

Comment: I got the solution of the problem. As REDIS does random sampling we can not sure all the keys will be picked the for LRU eviction.